# Hide columns not working properly with server side processing in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using jquery datatables(1.10.9) with server side processing.

```
    tab = $('#'+div).dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">frltip',
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bAutoWidth" : false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sScrollY": "550px",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bFilter": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 2 ] },{ "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 12 ] },{ "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 13 ] }],
        "oTableTools": {},
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'data/getdata',
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {

        },
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ){
            // Processing data like:  
            //  $('td:eq(2)', nRow ).html( 'Test' );
        }
    });

    // Hiding 5th column
    tab.fnSetColumnVis( 5, false); //Does not work.Removes the column header but not the row data.
```

How do I get hide column to work properly with server side processing in jquery datatables?

Comment: Did you check whether this works with local data?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Basically, it fetches server data again on tab.fnSetColumnVis call and while rendering it shows all the data in aaData although column header is hidden.

Comment: did you try refreshing `dataTables`?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work as follows:

```
        fnDrawCallback: function() {
            $('td:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(3)').hide();
        }]
```

tab.fnSetColumnVis( 3, false) will not work because it re-fetches the data.Hence, had to do it using simple old jquery.

Answer (score 0):

fnSetColumnVis() function has 3rd property (true or false) that not rebind the data. so try with fnSetColumnVis(3,false,flase) may be it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You do it when you set up the datatable, using "ColumnDefs" thusly, where targets is the number of the column you want to hide:

```
tab = $('#'+div).dataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [{ targets: 5, visible: false }],
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">frltip',
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bAutoWidth" : false,
              ...
```

If you have 2 hidden columns, it will look like this:

```
"columnDefs": [{ targets: 5, visible: false }, { targets: 6, visible: false }],
```

Note:  column numbering starts at 0.